# How to set countdown timer in zetacomponents/workflow

Tags: php, workflow, zeta-components

How to set timer in Zetacomponents/workflow so that after timer goes off, it should proceed to some execution ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that exists such functionality within zeta components/workflow. In order to do that you would need to make a php file that starts or continues an execution and make a cron job that executes that php file.

If you mean timer in the sense that there is a php code that is performing some sort of countdown, then all you need is just proceed the execution after the countdown ends.